# C# infopath directory.getfiles access error

Tags: c#, infopath-forms-services

I need to use an infopath form and its embedded code to search a directory for files with a specific extension. This code will be used to populate a multi-line textbox based on the findings of the scan. As of now, I have it spitting out the error message to the form inside the catch statement.

```
        string directory = @"C:\Users\am21820\Desktop";

        try
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.prm", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            string result1 = ConvertStringArrayToString(files);
            MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Test_Field", this.NamespaceManager).SetValue(result1);
        }

        catch (Exception f)
        {
            MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Test_Field", this.NamespaceManager).SetValue(f.Message);
        }
```

I have tried the following in addition to what is above.

```
        //FileIOPermission permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, directory);
        //permission.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess;

        //try
        //{
        //    permission.Assert();
        //    permission.Demand();
        //}

        //catch (Exception f)
        //{
        //    MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Test_Field", this.NamespaceManager).SetValue(f.Message);
        //}
```

I am using InfoPath 2013 along with VS 2012 and VSTA was updated along with my transition to InfoPath 2013. I get the following error. This error is present no matter which directory I try to scan.

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design. You need full trust form to be able to access files.

Note that for Forms Services C# code runs on server - and you can't get any access to user local files.

Comment: Does this mean that what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: @Merfeld if you want InfoPath form you an do that (need to install to gain full trust), but you can't get it working as server form (as such code can't see client file system).